# Swift evaluates wrong a condition at runtime

Tags: swift, if-statement, runtime

I am facing the following issue:

I am executing a code where swift has to check if these 2 bools are different `isVisible` and `visible`. The values are different but when I print `print(isVisible != visible)`it gives me `false`. I have debugged the line of code and when I execute `po isVisible != visible` it gives me `true`.

The code that I am using:

```
func setTabbarVisible(_ visible: Bool) {
    guard let tabBar = tabBarController?.tabBar else {
        return
    }

    let anchorPoint = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - tabBar.frame.size.height
    let isVisible = (tabBar.frame.origin.y == anchorPoint)
    print("SUUU")
    print(isVisible != visible)
    if isVisible != visible {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: kAnimationDuration, animations: {
            if visible {
                tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: tabBar.frame.origin.x, y: anchorPoint, width: tabBar.frame.size.width, height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
                tabBar.alpha = kBarsAlpha
            } else {
                tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: tabBar.frame.origin.x, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, width: tabBar.frame.size.width, height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
                tabBar.alpha = 0
            }
        })


    }
}
```

My debug terminal:

[image: Debug terminal screenshot.]

As we can see when I stop the program the values are different and the condition it is true, but when I print the value or the if statement evaluates the condition is giving me false. (I have tried to stop it before the print, and before the if and when I stop it the value is always the same, so it can't be because of concurrency).

Comment: If you print `visible` and `isVisible` from your code, not from terminal, are the values the same?

Comment: You are evaluation condition before performing your work, it sounds ok to me, or you `if` statement would have been never executed

Comment: @ekaerovets Yes, I have posted an answer with more details if you want to check :)

Comment: @CZ54 I am evaluating the condition after performing the work, if not in the console wouldn't be printed different results neither, check the answer that I have posted :) (Still dunno the reason why it is happening)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

If I wrap the code inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` it works fine.

But I don't understand why is this happening because before it was being executed in the main thread as well:

Before wrapping it with the `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`:
[image: Before wrapping it.]

After wrapping it:

[image: After wrapping it]

Also when I printed the values of `isVisible` and `visible` it was returning me both true, but when I was debugging them (after printing the variable but before the print of the `isVisible != visible` statement it was returning me different values).

```
        print( "print isVisible \(isVisible)")
        print ( "print visible \(visible)")
        print(( "print isVisible != visible \(isVisible != visible)"))
        if isVisible != visible {
```

output:

[image: Terminal output]